# Sometimes My Phone Just Restarts

Tags: motorola-droid, reboot, motorola-milestone

Occasionally (maybe twice a month) my Milestone just reboots (goes black and then to the Android startup screen (but not all the way to the Motorola screen)). 
I presume that such behaviour could be caused a poorly written app. I have uninstalled a few but to no avail. Is there any sort of log that I could pull which would shed some light on this or even a dump file?
Could this restarting issue be caused by something else?

I am currently running Android 2.1 (no OTA update available for me, yet) on a Milestone and have had this problem since I bought it in December (when it was 2.0).

Comment: I've seen that once or twice on my Nexus One. I assumed it was a bad connection with the battery contacts or something along those lines.

Comment: Are you using any apps when this happens? I did find this about kernel panic (which causes a reboot) on android 2.1 on the Milestone while using openGL apps: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7944

Comment: I've had this happen, and it's usually related to me trying to do application/sync updates, and my wifi/mobile connection fails, causing the entire thing to spazz out

Comment: This happens on my Incredible once or twice a month.  I've taken to calling it my Android BSOD.  It's always happened when it was just sitting there, never while I was actively using an app.   I'm assuming its some background process failing while attempting to run an update.

Comment: same here... I didn't find any particular pattern... I've got "Task Manager" on "auto-kill" to handle high-memory condition but still reboots from time to time.

Comment: @ninjaPixel Have you had any luck in the last few months?

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/how-can-i-determine-the-cause-of-random-device-reboots

Answer (score 3):

I have uninstalled TaskKiller as I read that these types of applications can cause stability issues on Android 2.1 and 2.2. So far so good...

Comment: I got excited too soon. Have had a couple of restarts recently. I presume that it must be due to some 3rd party process. Realistically though, I don't want to delete every app from my phone to find the cause, because 1) this will take ages and 2) I downloaded those apps for a reason

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer the question. But anyway, Restart generally occurs  when,

1. Phone is going out of resources, (Memory)
2. Bad Battery contacts, due to frequent pullouts.
3. Faulty apps leading to crash and screens of death.

I am saying so as Android too is an OS and these are the basic nature of an OS.  So if your Milestone is rooted, use XDA Assistant from Market and do some tweaks to your phone like

1. See your startup list and remove unwanted services while boot.
2. Also download InfoLLc  CacheCleaner to clean cache on regular intervals.
3. Install AdBlockers to block unwanted ads, sometimes they leads to crash.
4. Remove all apps that are not in use.
5. Instead of Auto Cleaning , do manual memory cleanup {RAM} using taskkillers.
6. Dont use any Battery Defenders as they too run their own service on the phone 24X7 {in wake phone} and consumes memory.
7. Use App2SD and try to move all your apps from pHone memory to your SD Card.

Finally I would like to say, keep your OS as light(clean) as possible.

Comment: Doubtful... faulty apps, according to Android sandboxed execution environment, are supposed to never let the phone crash. The phone crashes only when the ROM or the hardware is faulty, by design... I fully agree with possible causes 1 and 2 anyway

Comment: Well, let me clarify... If an app eats too much memory we may fall in case 1 but OutOfMemoryException is supposed to be thrown by OS if that happens. "Faulty" in the means of not catching exceptions never lead to reset: the app crashes and system detects the crash safely

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. One possible reason is that the graphics card does not support it. Delete graphics, especially pics attached in the phonebook. Everytime I am tempted to attach pics to the phonebook, I get this problem.

Hope it will help.