# Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc randomly reboots

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, reboot, sony-xperia-arc

I realise this might be a repeat question, or discussed at length in some related posts, please don't hesitate to discipline me if I'm being redundant.

I just really want to know not only if anyone else is experiencing random reboots on their Xperia Arcs (or any similar phone), but also if they've successfully resolved the issue? This is driving me completely insane, and I'm really disappointed because I really love my phone!

I've done a hard-reset, deleted everything off the SD card, and updated the phone to the latest available software from Sony Ericsson (Android v2.3.4). I've installed only 1 application, the logcat application mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1398), but that was after my phone rebooted TWICE today, and I also have no idea what log information I'm looking for...

I've [read this post by Zano](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/why-does-my-xperia-x10-spontaneously-reboot), as well as [this one by ninjaPixel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/370/sometimes-my-android-just-restarts) with no avail.

I refuse to believe that 'jimmy-ing' in a piece of paper to make the battery make contact better is the solution - as the battery in my phone is pretty tight already, and I've witnessed my phone reboot while simply lying on the desk - but I've tried that too and will continue to monitor...

ANY help will be greatly appreciated, and I'll continue to research and post back any additional information I find. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE #1:**

So far so good, no additional apps have been installed, and I've removed the logcat app that was on there as it wasn't helping assess anything. I've also installed a very professional piece of paper between the battery and the outside cover to help keep it more secure than usual. Holding thumbs..!

**UPDATE #2:**

Almost 2 weeks after my previous update, and still no reboot. It seems that although I wouldn't believe it to be as a result of the battery not connecting properly, it didn't mean that it wasn't the battery...I'll make this the last update, and say, in my case, the problem was because the battery wasn't connecting properly and adding a small piece of paper between the battery and the outside cover has done the trick. Thanks all for reading, and for your time and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it didn't seem to have anything to do with any software configuration or combination on my phone and was purely hardware related. This is not to say that in some cases the software you may or may not have on your device would be causing a memory leak / stack overflow and causing your device to reboot as a result.

I couldn't, and wouldn't, believe it, but after adding a small piece of paper between the battery and the phone under the back cover, my Xperia Arc hasn't rebooted for 3 weeks, whereas before it would reboot around twice a day.

Once again, thanks all for the suggestions and comments. I'll continue to monitor my phone, but I don't foresee any future reboots...related to the battery anyway...

Comment: I have tried all the things mentioned here to stop my phone from the reboot problem but still to now since yesterday the error is recurring. More suggestions please.

Comment: Has your phone always rebooted, or is it something you did yesterday specifically that's causing it, such as installing a new application or dropping it? Sorry if this seems strange, but reboots on the Arcs seem to be so specific..!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your phone to the latest firmware 4.0.2.A.0.62. I bet yours is 4.0.2.A.0.58

If you can't update the phone over OTA or PC Suite, use WOTAN to update the phone to 4.0.2.A.0.62. The reboot problem occurred on nearly all SE Xperia Models.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I've actually got version 4.0.2.A.42, and after running the update service I was informed that I already have the latest version running and I don't need to update. I suspect it's possible global region version limitation...thanks again for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and even sent my arc to a service centre for repair who said it's fine.
I was about to send the battery in for examination when I noticed black marks on the gold contacts. I cleaned the contacts and it's never restarted since (in around 7 months)

Comment: Awesome, good tip and good to know...thanks for the answer Callum!