# My Samsung Galaxy S2 is constantly shutting down

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, reboot, shutdown

Recently, whenever I am using an app or doing something on my phone other than texting or reading, my phone will up and shut off on me. When I try to reboot sometimes it will get all the way back to the home screen, but it will show that I now have 90% less juice than I had before.

Other times the start up will will get hung up on the sprint graphic and just shut back down.

In either scenario I am not able to use my phone again until I plug it into the wall and restart. I also noticed recently that when I do this it will typically kick off yet another "update" from the playstore for an app... not sure if this has anything to do with it...

Any help and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, please see the [FAQ] on the how to ask questions, only one question post at a time... :) Or I suggest to re-edit your question :)

Comment: Sounds faulty, first inclination, is the handset over-clocked? rooted? The battery juice drain is a dead give-away of a hardware fault. Suggest you take it back to Sprint and explain what is happening... :)

Comment: i should have mentioned that once I finally get it to start up without failing the battery power reads close to what it was prior to the first shutdown, meaning the initial read of a drain was not in fact that case

Comment: I'd suggest you taking a look at [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/) The steps described there can do no harm (except for the "last resort" of a *factory reset*, which would also wipe your data and apps). Also check for apps you recently installed, maybe you picked a "faulty" one. Also consider looking at [Sometimes My Phone Just Restarts](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/370/) and [How can I determine the cause of random device reboots?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/)

Comment: Have you tried re-seating the battery?

Comment: yeah... i've tried, but to no avail. no matter what I try (at a very basic level) I cannot seem to stop the phone from shutting down randomly...