# Recently Used Apps crashing in portrait mode

Tags: crashes, recents-screen

When I try to switch to the "Recently Used Apps" screen (by holding the home button), the process `com.android.systemui` crashes.

However, in Landscape mode it works as usual (and rotating the device makes it crash again).

Device: `Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini`
Version: `4.4.2`
ROM: `Stock`

**EDIT:** The system was not modified in any way (e.g. no root access).

Where can I find logs/files that provide me with additional info i.o. to trace the problem? Or what can I do to make it stop crashing (preferably not reseting)?

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the issue mysteriously disappeared today and I cannot reproduce it any more.

Comment: Is that allways like that? Did recents worked fine in landscape or it was allways crashing? You might look at logcat there is a lot of apps for that but I don't know if you'll be able to look at it because you don't have root.

Comment: This is becoming a common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check logs there are a few options, for instance:

1. Given that you have a Samsung, try opening `SysDump` by going to Phone dialer -> *#9900# (no need to press Dial).
   To get the logs, you might need to root your phone. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876731/2707864) shows methods for accessing files in `data/data` without rooting, and it may apply to `data/log` as well.
2. Use the adb to check the output of `dmesg`.
3. Use [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat).
   Details for checking an app adapted from [here](https://testlio.com/question/how-to-get-consolecrash-logs-for-android), it may require some tweaking for Recently Used Apps, if useful at all:

   1. Start your target app (e.g., "Myapp") on the device. If it crashes, repeat this step 2-3 times.
   2. Next start "aLogCat app" and wait for approximately ~1 minute.
   3. Press the "Menu" button and select "Filter".
   4. Type "Myapp" in the text field and press "OK" button.
   5. Wait for approximately ~1 minute.
   6. Press "Menu" button and select "Share".
   7. Collect the log via any sharing option you have access (e.g., email, Bluetooth).
4. Use [CatLog - Logcat Reader!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en). You might need root Access.

For completeness, I leave here a few related posts

[Android device crash logs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96195/android-device-crash-logs)

[How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407984/how-to-locate-app-crash-logs-in-android-phone

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305180/error-erasing-old-data-from-logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can get the log with this application installed [CatLog - Logcat Reader!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en). Try to read log immediately after the exception.