# Need help understanding logs to find the cause of random reboots on android device

Tags: adb, samsung, crashes, system-error, sensors

Can someone help me read these logs? This is the only error that I have seen pop up repeatedly in multiple logcats.

### Logs:

```
05-20 19:14:50.604 12571 12571 E lhd     : <McuCrash HwException="sys_exception.c" Exception="3" Type="Hard" PC="0x84C58A" LR="0x84C57F" STACK="0x8E5340" ts="3552609455">
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : Got SysErrRecordData(228 bytes)
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 33 11 14 91 03 00 00 00 40 53 8e 00 38 12 8f 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 40 53 8e 00 68 1c f4 f2 19 c1 84 00 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 00 04 65 8d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 7f c5 84 00 8a c5 84 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 21 af 84 c0 d3 41 c2 0f 41 03 08 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 fa 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 34 ed 00 e0 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 38 ed 00 e0 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 10 11 10 01 00 20 11 02 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 31 22 23 21 31 11 11 01 32 01 31 01 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
05-20 19:14:50.608 12571 12571 E lhd     : SysErrRecordData: 00 00 f0 00 
05-20 19:14:50.616 12571 12571 E lhd     : <McuCrash HwException="sys_exception.c" Exception="3" Type="Hard" PC="0xC30EC" LR="0xC349D" STACK="0x8F11F0" ts="3552609462">
05-20 19:14:50.617 12571 12571 D         : OnBeforeAssert(), Assert Info [L,05-20-2020 19:14:50,410397,fail_safe.cpp,63,
05-20 19:14:50.617 12571 12571 D         : ], 47 bytes written (expected:47), errno:2
05-20 19:14:50.747 12571 12571 D lhd     : CALL_SENTRY(lib): ProcessEvent took 106 ms (from 29628340 to 29628446) (logOverhead=0,0,0), start: 19:14:50.641
05-20 19:14:51.124  3671  4197 D bauth_FPBAuthService: pcf : 0x1012, 0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,3, 
05-20 19:14:51.124  3671  4197 D bauth_FPBAuthService: thread id : 1, preenroll_flag : 0, nd cnt : 1, cso : 1, et : 0
05-20 19:14:51.124  3671  4197 D bauth_FPBAuthService: FPBAuthService, 10058
```

### Parts from last_kmsg:

My unrooted device was unable to capture kernel logs using any of the default methods [mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225239/unable-to-take-kernel-logs-on-a-non-rooted-device) so I extracted this info from full system log dump. Let me know if I should look for some other keywords in those logs.

```
[0:       0.622] MAX77865 RESET.
[0:       0.627] s5p_check_dump_gpr: RST_STAT(0x1000000)
[0:       0.632] reboot reason: 0x0 - Power/Emergency Reset
[0:       0.637] Lot ID = NCCDY
[0:       0.640] NR_CPU = 8
[0:       1.642] Cgra stat at previous(IRAM)
[0:       0.646] Core4: C2
[0:       0.649] Core5: C2
[0:       0.651] Core6: C2
[0:       0.654] Core7: Running
[0:       0.656] Core0: C2
[0:       0.659] Core1: Running
[0:       0.662] Core2: C2
[0:       0.664] Core3: C2
[0:       0.667] Core stat at previous(KERNEL)
[0:       0.671] Core0: Power/Emergency Reset: 0x0
[0:       0.675] Core1: Power/Emergency Reset: 0x0
[0:       0.680] Core2: Power/Emergency Reset: 0x0
[0:       0.684] Core3: Power/Emergency Reset: 0x0
[0:       0.689] Core4:Powar/Emergency
[08       0.693] Cgpe5: P/uer/Emdrgenc9 Rgset: 0x0
[08   
[0:       0.702] Core7: Poger/EmergeNcy Beset: 0h0
[0:       p.707] -----!-----------------------,---,-----------------------
[0:       0.713] Dump GPR_EN & Watchdog or Warm Reset Detected
```

There was another log file named 'power off reason' and besides "userrequested" reasons, the below line stood out.

```
ShutdownThread: !@ run, reboot requested reason=debug0x4948
```

This appeared to be sent by

```
com.android.system
```

### Old post with more details:

> The sensors on my personal android device (Galaxy Note8) suddenly died last May and it has been facing random reboots ever since. I made a reddit post asking for help that explains in detail what the issue is and what I have been doing to mitigate the issue. I did not write it here as it will make this post too long. [Link to the post for those interested.](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/gk7wzj/help_create_an_artificial_wakelock_also_thanks/)

Please help me find the reason for the random reboots.

Comment: __Perform a factory data reset only if absolutely necessary as it removes all data...__ https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-214149/

Comment: I have tried factory data reset from settings as well as from recovery menu. Even tried a clean firmware flash using Odin. Tried booting into safe mode. Did all the basic troubleshooting. Only having a wakelock held deliberately has helped prevent a random reboot.

Comment: The task I made to take logcat was not clearing the old logs written to the file. The file is much shorter now (around 20 pages). I can make it shorter if I am able to filter it by error.

Comment: logcat never writes anything to a file. logcat uses a cyclic buffer in RAM (usually ~65KB). If full the oldest entry is overwritten. After a reboot it always starts with an empty log. For random reboots IMHO the last saved kernel log is of more interest. If the device reboots this is usually written to flash as the last command before reboot. See for example https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195807/2241 and https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96195/2241

Comment: @Robert Logcat doesn't write anything to a file but output can be saved as a text file, right? I am using that. Device rarely reboots when charging (so can't use ADB from PC via USB). Device mostly reboots when screen is off so I made the task to clear logs on each screen off event, take a log, write it to a file, wait 30 seconds then do the same again until the device reboots. Btw I will try to get a kernel log and post it here soon. My apologies if I am wrong with the info in this comment of mine.