# Unable to take kernel logs on a non-rooted device

Tags: adb, kernel, logging

I am trying to take kernel logs but so far have only got errors like 'permission denied', 'path does not exist' or 'kernel log does not exist'.

I have tried [this kernel panic link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195807/kernel-panic-problem-for-android-samsung), [this crash logs link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96195/android-device-crash-logs), [this link that suggests how to take logcat and kernel logs simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652605/taking-logcat-and-kernel-logs-simultaneously),[the kernel log option in this secret menu](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2960948), [this link suggesting console-ramoops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic),[this XDA tutorial](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-take-logs-in-android/) and several other links.

#### List of commands tried:

1. cat /proc/last_kmsg
2. dmesg
3. cat /proc/kmsg
4. cat /dev/kmsg
5. cat /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops
6. *#9900# (Samsung only)

I am doing this in response to a comment on [this post of mine](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225106/need-help-reading-logcats-to-find-the-cause-of-random-reboots-on-android-device). Any suggestions?

### Edit:

So I have been able to get logs using *#9900#. The kernel log option didn't work but I set debug mode to high, let the reboot happen and then used the inbuilt option to copy logs to storage. The device restarted and showed 'watchdog reset' after which I force restarted. Along with many other files, texts, logs, **it has mention of /proc/last_kmsg** in a txt file. I will see if it is useful and share in the original post.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I have just been successful in getting the required logs using option 6 mentioned in post. Your link looks interesting and I will give it a try too tomorrow. Thank you.