# S21 Ultra freezing, then rebooting. Intermittent issue. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: reboot

I have an S21 Ultra that will randomly freeze, then reboot. Sometimes it happens once a day, sometimes 10+ times per day. There seems to be no rhyme or reason.

I am only using like 50GB of 256 GB for storage, RAM was sitting pretty at 5GB utilization, everything is completely up to date. I have not rooted the phone, or done anything crazy with the software side. All apps are legitimate Play Store apps. There have been no hard drops/screen damage/water damage. I have already factory reset the device (and then restored from SmartSwitch. I used it in safe mode for ~2 days with no issues, but, I don't know if it was because I was using safe mode, or if the reboot just... didn't happen.

How can I troubleshoot this? It seems that you have to have the device actively connected to a computer to debug and that the logs are dumped on a reboot. I tried running the log export and reviewing the logs from the device, but I can't find anything helpful.

I work in Linux/IT/Software development, so I am pretty well equipped to try practically anything.

Thanks a whole bunch!

Comment: If the device crashes a kernel panic is likely the cause. You can try to get the last kernel log. See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225239/2241